# hibernate property formula how to get more than 1 row?

Tags: hibernate, properties, formula

In the hibernate mapping file I use property formula to get any value.

```
<property name="price" type="double" formula="(select SUM(amount) ...) />
```

But it allows to get only 1 row. How can I get lisf of rows? 
I understand that "property" is not suitable, but it's impossible to add formula to set or list.

Of course I just want to get values without adding new classes. 
I just have the sql request and expect to get list or set for existed class.

Comment: Sounds like you really want to have a 1:m reference, without a 'proper' reference field.
Is this correct?

Comment: Well, I need to add a list to my class. It will use ONLY to show any additional information concerning this object. And this tables aren't covered with mapping file, 'cause they are used by another application.

Answer (score 1):

Formula properties only operate on the current row.  If you want to perform aggregate functions, you need to write a specific query to fetch them. See the [section of the hibernate docs that handle aggregate functions](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core.old/reference/en/html/queryhql-aggregation.html).

Comment: Yeah, I can write a query which returns more tnen 1 row, but how can I store this result in my class? 
And I want to set this query in my mapping xml file related with my class.

Comment: You can't, that's what I'm saying. You can't have a property of a row which contains data from multiple rows, that doesn't make sense.

Comment: I'm not saying that I want exactly property. Let it be list or set or something else, doesn't matter, but how?

Comment: Link is out-dated. might be [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-aggregate-functions) now

Answer (score 1):

If your formula returns more than one row, you need to link the statement with the entity identifier, for example:

select *column name*
from *table*
where *table*.identifier = entity_identifier

Regarding to apply this to a set of values, maybe a group by function can apply. I once used group_concat from mysql for example to show a list of values. The bad thing of that is that the formula was coupled to mysql native dialect, but it worked.

Comment: Nice to have knowledge about group_concat function. Thanks for posting the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Formulas apply to single-valued properties only; not to collections. You can, however, specify a [custom SQL statement to be used for loading a collection](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/querysql.html#querysql-load).

The tricky part here is that from your question it sounds like what you want is a collection of elements (`double` price) rather than entities; I've never tried to specify custom loader 
 for something like that and so am not sure whether it will work. Documentation is rather silent on that issue.

If the above does not work, another option is to define your `SELECT` as a view and map collection that way (again, as collection of elements).

Finally, you can also run a query like `skaffman` suggested. You'll need to invoke that query and populate a collection on your entity manually when appropriate (e.g. within your DAO after entity is loaded) ro you can [define an appropriate listener](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/events.html#objectstate-events) and do it there.

Comment: dead link... code example would have been more useful

Comment: Yup, dead links are very lame.